# Google Script Sort Column Ascending Order with Blank Cells at Bottom

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have the below script running to sort column E in an ascending order. Each row is a different task and column E is the deadline. I have another piece of script running which deletes the deadline in column E once 'Complete' has been selected in another column. Hence, completed tasks will show empty cells in column E.

The deadlines are currently sorting from closest to furthest away, however E cells that are now empty are not moving to the bottom. I am a Scripts newbie and cannot see the issue. **Any help to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.**

```
function onEdit(event){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("2020");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 5;
  var tableRange = "A2:I998";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

The issue is not the code.

As stated in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite):

> The onEdit(e) trigger runs automatically when a **user** changes the value
> of any cell in a spreadsheet.

- Namely, the `onEdit` trigger is activated only when the user edits the
  value of a particular sheet. If the edit comes from scripts or
  formulas then the `onEdit` function won't be triggered.
- In your case, you have a script that deletes the content of cells in column E and hence `onEdit` is not triggered and as a result there no sorting is being done.

### Workaround Solution 1:

- Since you can't take advantage of the `onEdit` since the deletion of
  a value happens by a script.
- An obvious workaround would be to incorporate the sorting
  functionality inside the script that deletes a cell in column E.

Let's say that the `deleteCell` function is responsible for deleting the content of a cell in column E. As soon as this function runs, after deleting the cell, also sort the data range right after that by calling the `sortE` function:

```
function deleteCell(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("2020");
  sh.getRange("E3").clearContent();
  sortE();
}

function sortE(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("2020"); // assuming you want to sort sheet "2020"
  const columnToSortBy = 5;
  const tableRange = "A2:I998";  
  const range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
}
```

In this case, `sortE` won't be manually called by you. You only need to make sure that `deleteCell` is executed.

### Workaround Solution 2:

You can create a time trigger to check (every minute or so) if column E contains an empty cell. If it does, then run `sortE` of the script above (in workaround solution 1). To create such a trigger for `sortE`, you can run `createTrigger` once (just make sure `sortE` is somewhere in the script editor):

```
function sortE(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("2020"); // assuming you want to sort sheet "2020"
  const columnToSortBy = 5;
  const tableRange = "A2:I998";  
  const range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
}

function createTrigger(){
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("sortE").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
}
```

and execute **only** and **once** `createTrigger` to initiate the trigger:

[image]